# Is there a way to write multiple classes into a python file from text received from the user?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to receive input from the user (by using wx.Choice) and then based on that number, editing a .py file to edit the contents of each class based on the number chosen

I have a GUI set up using wxpython and it has three options. A dropdown menu with the numbers 1-5, a title text box, and a body multi-line text box. I can successfully write the class to the file when choosing a number, typing in a title, and typing a body, but if I choose a new number, it just overwrites what ive already written to the text file with the new text in the GUI

here are the text panels and boxes:

```
self.numberChoices = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
qnNumber_label = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Quicknote Number:", pos=(20, 30))
self.number_Control = wx.Choice(panel, pos=(140, 30), size=(50, -1), choices=self.numberChoices)
widgets.append(qnNumber_label)
widgets.append(self.number_Control)

# Quicknote title text panel creation
qnTitle_label = wx.StaticText(panel, label='Quicknote Title:', pos=(20, 60))
self.title_Control = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos=(140, 60))
widgets.append(qnTitle_label)
widgets.append(self.title_Control)

# Quicknote body text panel creation
qnBody_label = wx.StaticText(panel, label='Quicknote Text:', pos=(20, 90))
self.body_Control = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE, pos=(140, 90), size=(300, 200))
widgets.append(qnBody_label)
widgets.append(self.body_Control)
```

and they are being called and written here when the save button is clicked:

```
quicknoteNumber = "class QN%s():" % self.number_Control.GetSelection()
quicknoteTitle = "\ttitle = '%s'" % self.title_Control.GetValue()
quicknoteBody = "\tnote = %s\n" % self.body_Control.GetValue().split("#")

ret = [quicknoteNumber, quicknoteTitle, quicknoteBody]
print ("\n".join(ret))
# print(ret)

file = open('config.py', 'w')

file.write("\n".join(ret))
file.close()

confirmation_text = 'Your quicknote was updated successfully!'
dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, confirmation_text, 'Success', wx.OK)  # wx.OK|wx.ICON_INFORMATION
result = dlg.ShowModal()
dlg.Destroy()
```

here are the desired results:

```
class QN0():
    title = 'title'
    note = ['a line of notes\nanother line of notes\none last line of notes']

class QN1():
    title = 'title'
    note = ['a line of notes\nanother line of notes\none last line of notes']
```

but instead, when I choose a new number from the drop down, it just replaces what I previously wrote to the file. Ideally id like to overwite classes of the same number since this is an editing GUI for quicknotes. (e.g. if Class QN0 already exists, when I choose QN0 from the dropdown, it would edit Class QN0 instead of rewriting it a second time).

Comment: use mode "a" (append) instead of "w" (write) when you open file.

Comment: furas, is there a way to overwrite if the class already exists? the 'a' worked but now im getting multiple of the same classes in the config.py file

Comment: yes, you can open with "w" to delete old content. Now you have to know when to open with "w" and when with "a".

Comment: but I would do this in different way. At start I would read all from file so I could change it in memory (add, delete, edit) and then I would write all content again using "w"

Comment: I guess the hard part is that I only want old content deleted if that particular class is being edited. I dont want any of the classes deleted, unless I choose one of the classes from the dropdown and it already exists in the note. Is there a way to run a loop to check for an existing class in the file and then deleting it before adding the edited class notes?

Comment: to delete anything in file you have to read it to memory, delete some elements from memory and write rest back in file. Your  data looks like table with 3 columns so you could keep it as `csv` file to easily read it back as list. Or as JSON file to read it easily as python dictionary. Or maybe you should use module `pickle` for this. There are also modules to keep configuration as .ini or .yaml. Keeping it as .py may not be good idea.

Comment: Yeah I will definitely look into that. I think any file type would probably be better than a .py file, but im also picking up a program that was made in-house for my job and thats how they have the existing code written. I thought of creating a different file for each quicknote thats being edited as a workaround for now, but now its not liking my if loop. instead of the one write command, I have this:

Comment: if self.number_Control.GetSelection() == 1:
            with open('QN0.py', 'w') as file:
                file.write("\n".join(ret))
                file.close()
        elif self.number_Control.GetSelection() == 2:
            with open('QN1.py', 'w') as file:
                file.write("\n".join(ret))
                file.close()

Comment: Read the contents of the file, load them into a dictionary, then add,edit or delete before writing them back. Or, use something specifically written to handle `.ini` files, such as `configobj` https://configobj.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configobj.html another is `configparser`

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, you must open the file with the option "**a+**" (for append) instead of "**w**".

For example:

```
f=open("config.py", "a+")
```

Now, you can write whatever you want and it will be added to the end of the file:

```
 f.write("Appended line!!!")
```

More info:

https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html#2

**Edit:**

Reading your last comment, try to read the entire content, process it (delete what you want for example with regular expressions) and then write it the entire content again.

Regards.